# Олимпиадная задача - оптимальный выбор

Tags: олимпиада, task

*Прошу помочь решить задачу. На мой взгляд задача сложная. Честно говоря не представляю как её решать. Хотя есть идея просто перебрать все комбинации воинов, но их слишком много получится, поэтому вынужден обратиться за помощью) Подскажите идею для решения))*

**Задачка**

Вы счастливый мэр процветающей столицы Берляндии, но вот незадача — в пригороде поселился ужасный монстр, который атакует торговые караваны, курсирующие между столицей и соседними городами. Чтобы избавиться от монстра, вы решили нанять команду героев в городской гильдии авантюристов.
Гильдия предлагает n воинов и у i-го воина hi единиц здоровья и di единиц атаки. У монстра, которого надо убить, a единиц здоровья.

Пока у монстра осталось положительное число единиц здоровья и остался хотя бы один герой с положительным количеством единиц здоровья, происходит следующее:

Сначала каждый живой герой наносит монстру урон, равный значению его атаки. Если здоровье монстра упало до нуля, битва завершается;
Затем, если монстр еще жив, он наносит каждому герою по единице урона. Каждый герой, чей уровень здоровья упал до нуля, умирает.
Так как казна ограничена, вы хотите нанять наименьшее число героев, чтобы убить монстра. Но вы также не хотите, чтобы умер хотя бы один из героев команды, поэтому вам надо нанять наименьшее число героев, чтобы они могли убить монстра без потерь.

**Примечание**

В первом наборе входных данных достаточно трёх героев, чтобы убить монстра без потерь. Например, это могут быть герои с номерами 2, 3, 4. Их суммарная атака равна 6 и они убивают монстра за две атаки.

Во втором наборе входных данных первого теста есть единственный герой и его силы достаточно, чтобы сразу убить монстра.

**Формат входных данных**

В первой строке входные данных содержится одно целое число t (1 ≤ t ≤ 1000) — количество наборов входных данных.
Далее следует описание наборов.
В первой строке каждого набора содержится целое число a (1 ≤ a ≤ 109) — здоровье монстра.
Во второй строке каждого набора содержится целое число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 2⋅105) — общее число воинов, которых предлагает гильдия для найма.
В третьей строке каждого набора содержатся n целых чисел h1,h2,…,hn (1 ≤ hi ≤ 109) — единицы здоровья каждого героя.
В четвертой строке каждого набора содержатся n целых чисел d1,d2,…,dn (1 ≤ di ≤ 109) — единицы атаки каждого героя.
Гарантируется, что сумма n по всем наборам входных данных не превосходит 2⋅105

**Формат выходных данных**

Для каждого набора входных данных в отдельной строке выведите единственное целое число:
минимальное количество героев, которое нужно нанять, чтобы убить монстра без потерь,
или −1, если это невозможно.

**Пример**

```
Входные данные: 
2
12
5
1 2 3 3 4
2 4 1 1 1
10
1
1
14
Выходные данные:
3
1
```

*Ах да, ограничение по времени 2 секунды. Так как требуется вывести необходимое количество воинов, а не их индексы, то, возможно, не нужно перебирать все варианты или что-то типа такого*

Взяв за основу идею @StanislavVolodarskiy я написал вот это на python:

```
answer = list()
for _ in range(int(input())):
    a = int(input())
    n = int(input())
    hp_war = list(map(int, input().split()))
    d_war = list(map(int, input().split()))
    attack = dict()
    for i in range(n):
        attack[d_war[i]] = attack.get(d_war[i], list()) + [hp_war[i]]
    attack = {key: sorted(attack[key], reverse=True) for key in sorted(attack, reverse=True)}

    max_h_lvl, k = max(hp_war) + 1, n + 1
    h_left, h_level, h_right = 1, max_h_lvl // 2, max_h_lvl
    while True:
        sum_attack, flag, cnt = 0, 0, 0
        for a_w in attack:
            for h_w in attack[a_w]:
                if h_w >= h_level:
                    cnt += 1
                    sum_attack += a_w
                    if sum_attack * h_level >= a:
                        flag = 1
                        break
                    continue
                break
            if flag == 1:
                break
        if flag:
            k = min(k, cnt)
        if h_right - h_left <= 1:
            break
        if flag:
            h_right, h_level = h_level, (h_level + h_left) // 2
        else:
            h_left, h_level = h_level, (h_level + h_right) // 2

    if k == n + 1:
        answer.append(-1)
    else:
        answer.append(k)

for ans in answer:
    print(ans)
```

Валидное решение, на мой взгляд, но не на взгляд тестирующей системы. Всё-таки я что-то упускаю из виду. Но вот что?..

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Comment: `Взяв за основу идею @StanislavVolodarskiy` это вы моё предложение реализовывали, но он не обеспечивает оптимальности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groups` - словарь сопоставляющий здоровью список индексов героев с этим здоровьем. Словарь обрабатывается по увеличению здоровья. `h` - текущий уровень здоровья.

`heroes` - список героев, упорядоченный по убыванию урона. `k` превращает список героев в стек. В бою участвуют герои из `heroes[:k]` но только те, у которых здоровье ≥ `h`.

`count` - число героев в бою, `damage` - их суммарный урон за один шаг.

Цикл состоит из четырёх шагов:

1. В начале цикла имеем команду. Пока её суммарный урон достаточен для победы над монстром за `h` шагов, снимаем героев по одному. Соответственно корректируются `count` и `damage`.
2. Теперь у нас команда, которой недостаточно для победы. Добавляем героев пока их не станет достаточно.
3. Если героев хватило для победы, рапортуем наверх количество героев для победы за `h` раундов. Иначе ничего не делаем.
4. Готовимся к следующим раундам - удаляем всех героев из текущей группы здоровья. В следующих сражениях они не нужны - не хватит здоровья.

Может показаться что в пунктах 1. и 2. делается лишняя работа. Это так но её не много. Если изначально команда мала, то первый цикл исполнится ноль раз. Если изначально команда достаточна или слишком велика, то второй цикл исполнится один раз.

Сложность *NlogN* для сортировок и *N* для цикла по здоровью.

```
def counts(a, heroes):
    groups = {}
    for i, (_, h) in enumerate(heroes):
        groups.setdefault(h, []).append(i)

    k = 0
    count = 0
    damage = 0
    for h, indices in sorted(groups.items()):
        while k > 0 and damage * h >= a:
            k -= 1
            if heroes[k][1] >= h:
                count -= 1
                damage -= heroes[k][0]
        while k < len(heroes) and damage * h < a:
            if heroes[k][1] >= h:
                count += 1
                damage += heroes[k][0]
            k += 1
        if damage * h >= a:
            yield count
        for i in indices:
            if i < k:
                count -= 1
                damage -= heroes[i][0]


def solve(a, h, d):
    return min(counts(a, sorted(zip(d, h), reverse=True)), default=-1)


def main():
    t = int(input())
    for _ in range(t):
        a = int(input())
        input() # skip n
        h = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
        d = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
        print(solve(a, h, d))


main()
```

Comment: Браво! Количество наличествующих уровней здоровья не превышает N - то, что я не подумал брать в расчёт...

Answer (score 0):

Сортируем по убыванию здоровья. Считаем сумму с накоплением по группам с одинаковым здоровьем, умноженную на минимальное здоровье, от наиболее здоровых. Как превысили здоровье моба - стоп. Сортируем остаток по убыванию силы. Начинаем выкидывать по одному с самых слабых. Как не убиваем - предыдущий вариант и есть решение.

Comment: Если я верно понял, это соберет мобов с высоким здоровьем и низким уроном и пропустит мобов с низким здоровьем и высоким уроном.  Условно, сто героев с силой 1 и здоровьем 50 и один герой с силой 100 и здоровьем 2.